# Alguém quer arrumar a *tag* Forms?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

A *tag* [forms](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms) provavelmente não deveria existir. Mesmo que tenha um motivo deveria ser usada do jeito certo.

Tenho como certo que ela usada com C#, VB.NET ou algo .NET em quase todos os casos é porque a pessoa está usando a tecnologia Windows Forms, e a usa de forma equivocada, muitas vezes junto com a [windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), o que é um claro erro porque a *tag* correta é a [winforms](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms), que muitas vezes já é usada também. Note que que o fato de não ter a de Windows não quer dizer que não seja correto usar WinForms.

Em outros casos provavelmente a pessoa está fazendo um formulário web ou algum formulário de alguma tecnologia, mas que não chama `forms`, e deveria usar [formulário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formul%c3%a1rio) no lugar dessa *tag*. Em alguns casos só deveria matar essa *tag*.

Tem casos que precisa

Tem mais algum caso diferente? Se tiver bom senso sinta-se a vontade pra consertar também, no fim eu acho que essa *tag* deve morrer, mas pode justificar depois da análise se acha que ainda faz sentido tê-la.

Estou preferindo deixar para alguém da comunidade fazer, mas se ninguém tomar essa responsabilidade eu posso fazer.

Se for fazer seria bom avisar e fazer de madrugada e final de semana porque pode afetar cerca de 100 perguntas e poluir a página principal, seria bom até fazer aos poucos.

Obrigado.

Comment: Estou disponível para ajudar Usarei as primeiras horas da manhã(será de madrugada no Brasil). Se fizer algo de errado não hesite em corrigir ou me notificar.

Comment: @ramaral acho que entendeu, né? A *tag* `windows` quase sempre será inútil ali também, inclusive porque hj WinForms poderia rodar fora do Windows e de fato roda pelo Mono, ainda que não tão bem assim.

Comment: Sim, julgo que sim. Não só retirar a forms mas fazer uma análise de eventuais tags a mais ou a menos.

Comment: Por que não fazemos um mutirão da limpeza e limpamos tags inúteis como `texto`, `windows`, `exportar`, `member`, `variavel` tudo de uma vez?

Comment: @CypherPotato podemos, mas é preciso fazer com cuidado, não pode todo mundo sair fazendo do jeito que bem entende. Eu tenho visto que quase todas discussões sobre *tags* acabam não chegando a uma conclusão e quando chega raramente alguém pega para fazer. Quando eu tenho certeza de alguma coisa eu nem discuto por causa disto. Muitas dessas são complicadas de arrumar, porque nem sempre é óbvio que a *tag* não deveria estar ali. Inclusive porque cada pessoa tem uma visão diferente de como uma *tag* deveria ser usada. Então sem consenso o jeito acaba sendo ficar como está.

Comment: @Maniero Existe algum padrão para a permanência de tags na comunidade? No qual ela se encaixa em determinadas regras e condições para continuar existindo (e evitar estes casos de tags inúteis)? *Digo após ela ser criada.*

Comment: Tem várias discussões sobre isso.

Comment: A tag formulários, pela descrição, aplica-se a formulários HTML. O que fazer com, por exemplo, Ruby on Rails e django, pelo que entendi, tem mais que simples HTML. E VBA e Delphi?

Comment: Me parece que é apenas formulário, não é algo que chama `forms`. Alguém pode dar opinião?

Comment: Quer dizer que se deveria retirar a referência a HTML na descrição da tag formulários e esta passaria a ser usada para tudo? Refiro-me a tudo onde é usada a palavra *Form*, ex: VBA Forms, Delphi Forms, Java Swing, etc. Assim eliminar-se-ia a tag forms.

Comment: @ramaral Se existes essas tecnologias com esses nomes, deveria retiranar sozinho e colocar o nome composto, como eu vi você fazer com `xamarin-forms` por exemplo. Só não estou afirmando os nomes. A questão do HTML é se é sobre HTML ou não. Em HTML puro não tem nada que chama `forms`, pode ter alguma tecnologia extra aplicada a ele. Não acho que seja obrigado eliminar a *tag* `forms`, se tiver um motivo pra ela existir pode deixar, mas acho que tudo ali está errado e não faz sentido mantê-la, mas só acho.

Comment: Pelo que me é dado a entender a tag forms está a ser usada como "relacionado a formulário". Você está a ser um pouco vago, não dá para ter a certeza sobre o que pensa. Posso entender que também acha que, pelas mesmas razões, a tag formulário deva ser retirada? Que fique claro que eu não estou a defender a existência ou não de qualquer das duas, apenas não quero tomar essa decisão sozinho.

Comment: @ramaral Só vago porque não sei bem o que é o ideal :) Eu acho que a *tag* deveria acabar, mas pode ser que você olhando ache motivos para mantê-la. Essas coisas só se define olhando os casos e quem está fazendo é você :) Pode ser que você veja um ou outro caso que ela se encaixe perfeitamente, que não deveria apagar ou trocar por outra

Comment: Pois eu também não, daí ter posto as questões :) Acho que a formulário também está a ser mal utilizada e você, não respondendo, não ajudou. Vou seguir o meu principio e não vou mexer naquelas em que tenho dúvida.

Comment: Sem dúvida `formulário` está ruim também. Pelo que vi o que você tem feito tá tudo certo.

Comment: Zé Finí! ......